# Project/work based desktop customization

Tags: customization

I would like to create customized desktops which contain the files and program/tool icons etc that I use for specific projects. I would also like to switch between different projects like I do when changes workspace.

Is this possible? If so how?

Zack

Comment: Without switching users?

Comment: Yes, the same user having different desktops for different projects....

Comment: Could you separate that in two questions?

Comment: Under KDE,they're called "activities". They are easy to setup. When I last tried them (a couple of years ago), they had issues, but it's likely that these are resolved by now. KDE can easily be used with ubuntu and several other distros (kubuntu, Mint, Arch, ...)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Gnome or xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe not the exact answer you need, but you could use shell scripts to open the apps + files you need for each project.
For example on Windows I use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). I have a script for each project, that just opens everything I need for that...